# Android Google Maps: Double Click on the MapView

Tags: android, click, maps, double

This question has been asked several times before and I have thoroughly read and followed the answers/comments. As a result I am able to produce the code below but the code responds only to `onDown()`, `onShowPress()`, `onLongPress()`. Following is the only class that I intend to enable to capture double click or double tap.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class GoogleAndroidMapsActivity extends MapActivity implements OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //To allow zooming along with panning around, enable it
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, this);
    gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

    mapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }); 
 }

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Double Tap");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Double Tap Event");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Single Tap Confirmed");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Down");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Fling");
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Long Press");
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Scroll");
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Show Press");
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Single Tap Up");
    return false;
}
}
```

But i do not understand why `onDoubleTap()` and `onDoubleTapEvent()` never get called. In fact the only thing that gets called is `onDown()`, `onShowPress()`, `onLongPress()`.

I even tried extending MapView as shown below and then using in my main class, `GoogleAndroidMapsActivity.java` but to no avail. I changed `main.xml` accordingly to reflect `AdvMapView.java`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class AdvMapView extends MapView implements OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener{

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public AdvMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet) {
    super(context, attrSet);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
    gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

    this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });        
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Double Tap");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Double Tap Event");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Single Tap Confirmed");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Down");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Fling");
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Long Press");
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Scroll");
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Show Press");
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GMaps", "Single Tap Up");
    return false;
}

}
```

And then using in `GoogleAndroidMapsActivity` as

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class GoogleAndroidMapsActivity extends MapActivity{

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //To allow zooming along with panning around, enable it
    AdvMapView mapView = (AdvMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 

 }

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

}
```

Also, `onDown()`, `onShowPress()`, `onLongPress()` get invoked only once, the first time I click/double click. After I get "Down", "Show Press" & "Long Press" in my logs, clicking/double clicking has no effect. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way, just put this brackets into your class body extending the MapView class

```
{
 final GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    getController().zoomInFixing((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
    return true;
  }
});

this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Specifically I wanted to override the default double tapping on an map (SupportMapFragment). The way I solved it (it is actually a workaround) is:
I created a framelayout that was filling the exact same area as my map fragment but it was rendered exactly after that.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Then I added a gesture listener to the "overlaying" fragment_wrapper and I was able to capture the double tap:

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new DoubleTapDetector());
fragmentWrapper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event){
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
});
```

and the DoubleTapDetector class is:

```
public class DoubleTapDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d("DoubleTapDetector", "Double Tap!");
                //DO ACTIONS HERE
        return true;
    }
}
```